# Optical Flow egomotion estimation

Tags: camera, rotation, motion, motion-detection, opticalflow

below you can see the result of the optical flow if a camera makes a translation movement. If the camera makes a roll rotation the result looks like the second picture. Is it possible to retrieve the yaw angle from a camera if its only rotation around the yaw axis?
I think in the optical flow you can recognize if the camera is rotating around the yaw axis (z-axis), but i don't know how to retrieve the information how much the cam has rotated.

I would be gradeful for any hints. Thanks

Translation:
[image]

Roll rotation:

[image]

Orientation of camera:

[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem? I am interested as well and would appreciate if you post the answer (if you found one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a pure rotation of your cam then you can use findhomography.  You need four point correspondence in your pictures. For a pure rotation the homography matrix is already a rotation matrix. Otherwise  you need to decompose the homograohy matrix.  For a camera movement off 6 dof you can  use the function find essential matrix and decompose this to translation and rotation.